# Facing issue in importing table with the year of current date

Tags: sql, oracle, import, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to power bi. I was trying to import oracle database using SQL query in the query editor.

I want only the records whose year matches with the current date's year. I tried using 'column_name LIKE "2019%"' 
, but the problem here is i cant change the condition every year. The column is in text format and the values are like this '20190009','20198873'. Here the first 4 numbers represent the year. 
Can anyone help me out in solving this?

COLUMN_NAME LIKE '2019%'

NOT ABLE TO USE SYSDATE() OR TODAY() FUNCTION TO GET DATE

Comment: You shouldn't be storing dates as text, but given that you are, `LIKE '2019%'` should in fact return all the records from 2019.  Can you add a reproducible sample to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `EXTRACT` function as following:

```
SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME,1,4) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend one of the following:

```
column_name like to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || '%'
```

or:

```
substr(column_name, 1, 4) = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')
```

However, you should fix your data model so the date column is stored as a `date`, not a string.